# Docker for Windows 10 Home error:Hardware assisted virtualization and data execution protection must be enabled in the BIOS

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, virtualization, docker

I want to use Docker in my Windows 10 Home Surface Pro 7 PC and the many sites say I should install wsl2 and then install Docker Desktop for Windows.

After the process, I launched Docker Desktop and I get this error message.

```
Hardware assisted virtualization and data execution protection must be enabled in the BIOS. See https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/troubleshoot/#virtualization
```

troubleshoot page says for Windows10 Home, I have to launch `Windows Feature` and check the `Virtual Machine Platform` and `Windows Subsystem for Linux`.(Instead of `Hyper-V` for Windows10 Pro)

I checked these item, but Docker Desktop still returns the same error

And this is surface pro 7 PC which does not have any item for virtualization on UEFI.

How can I use Docker on my PC?

Any information would be appreciated.

Comment: "How can I use Docker on my PC?" - If you are unable to enable hardware virtualization then you will be unable to use Docker Desktop on your device.  You should be able to use Docker through WSL2

Comment: Open the System information app (msinfo32.exe) and scroll to the end, there should be 4 entries starting with Hyper-V. Are they all showing "yes"?

Comment: @Ramhound Strange I have Windows 10 Home, too and I see all four entries in system info app.

Comment: @Robert - It's impossible to have Hyper-V installed and enabled on Windows 10 Home. Yes; I see that those entries would exist no matter what.